# Ignore whitespace when using preg_match

Tags: php

I'm using `preg_match` to try and capture the 'Data' in this html structure but currently it's not returning anything, I think this may be down to the whitespace?

Just wondering what's wrong in the `preg_match`?

**html**

```
  <td><strong>Title</strong></td>

                    <td>Data</td>
```

**php**

```
preg_match("~<td><strong>Title</strong></td>

                    <td>([a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+)</td>~", $html, $match);
```

Comment: Yes, the whitespace. There are regex placeholders [for that](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so no need to define a fixed number of spaces and linebreaks.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler using a DOM parser instead of Regex matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to reproduce the exact sequence of whitespace (which may be hard or even impossible due to line endings), just use `\s*` to indicate "any number (including zero) of whitespace characters" - this includes spaces, tabs, newlines, carriage returns... exactly what you need here.

Comment: like this? `preg_match("/<td><strong>Venue<\/strong><\/td><td>([a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+)<\/td>/\s*", $html, $match);`

Comment: No, I mean you should put the `\s*` where you want the whitespace to appear, in the middle of the pattern. Also, I'd suggest switching back to `~` for your delimiter, so you don't have to escape the slashes. Personally I like to use `()` as delimiters, so I don't have to escape anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, did not test before. \s* gives you 0 to infinity possible spaces, so it is your solution here.

```
preg_match("/<td><strong>Title<\/strong><\/td>\s*<td>([a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+)<\/td>/",
           $html, $match)
```

Tested it out. It works now :)

Comment: The `x` modifier ignores whitespace in the *pattern*, not the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from an html file, an xml parser can be a lot better.

Anyway, your regular expression won't match anything in more than one line unless you specify the modifier m (you can also specify the modifier s for the dot (.) to match new lines too ).

See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

Use s modifier

Read more about modifires [Modifiers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm)

```
preg_match_all('/<td><strong>Title<\/strong><\/td>.*<td>(.*)<\/td>/iUs',$cnt,$preg);
print_r($preg);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td><strong>Title</strong></td>

                    <td>Data</td>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data
        )

)
```